# formatted string to stream

Tags: c++, logging, stream, string-formatting

I'm sure I'm not the first one to encounter this situation, still, couldn't find anything specific neither here, nor generally.

I'm using an old logger, that uses the printf formatting... e.g.:

```
LOG_ERROR("Error Code: %d. Additional data %s", error.ID, error.serialize());
```

And want to move to a stream-style logger. e.g.:

```
LOG_ERROR("Error Code: " << error.ID << "Additional data: " << error.serialize());
```

Naturally, the code base is big and I want to automate this. I think I can come up with a script that does it, but it looks not so trivial... I'm sure there's a pretty simple way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not dare to automate that task.
You may rename all old LOG_ERROR to (something like) LOG_ERROR_FORMAT, let LOG_ERROR_FORMAT create a string and pass that to the new LOG_ERROR.

If you really want to go for it, I suggest a look at some printf implementation to get the parsing right

Comment: Since posting, I too came to a conclusion that there's no easy way out, but I'm going to take my chances and try and parse those along the lines of "find the first left bracket, then find the first quotes, then find the first not escaped "%", then replace it with the first thing you find after the last not escaped quotes..."

Comment: @SashaZh If you really want to go for it, I suggest a look at some printf implementation to get the parsing right.

Comment: That's eventually solved most of my problems, thanks!